# Ignore Physical Directory and Use Wordpress Permalink

Tags: wordpress, directory, permalinks

example.com/whitepapers/) in Wordpress and that on its own works fine. Recently I added a physical folder that stores my PDF whitepapers. A typical URL will be www.example.com/whitepapers/pdf.pdf.

Due to that folder, the permalink no longer works. Is there a way I can get around this? I want to keep the structure due to SEO purposes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name

No real solution so I will have to rename my directory and redirect the necessary files.